# Semaphore in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, semaphore

Code:

```dart
void _test() {
  print(1);
  Timer.run(() {
    print(2);
  });
  print(3);
}
```

Print 1 3 2.

I want print 1 2 3.

In iOS I can use Semaphore, how can I do this in flutter?

Comment: In general, prefer `async` functions that you `await`.  If you *must* use a `Timer`, you can have the `Timer` use a `Completer` and then you can `await` that `Completer`'s `Future` before doing `print(3)`.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin. `Completer ` can do the same like `Semaphore ` in iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @jamesdlin, I solved with his comment, below is desired code:

```dart
void _test() async {
  print(1);
  Completer<void> completer = Completer();
  Timer.run(() {
    print(2);
    completer.complete();
  });
  await completer.future;
  print(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Awaiting for a method to complete can be written inside a future

```dart
void _test() async{
  print(1);
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds : 0), (){
    print(2);
  });
  print(3);
}
//Output 1 3 2
```

```dart
void _test() async{
  print(1);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds : 0), (){
    print(2);
  });
  print(3);
}
//Output 1 2 3
```

In the second example the await will wait for the future to complete  and then move to the next task

Comment: You changed `Timer.run` to `Future.delayed`, however, `Timer.run` did not return future. This is a very important difference between them and you can't ignore.

Comment: Yeah i agree timer.run and future are not same. But just wrote what's generally used to await an execution.

Answer (score 1):

`Timer.run()` basically tells the program that here is a piece of code that should be executed but I don't care if it finishes before it reaches the code outside of this block.

If you want to wait a bit, use `Future.delayed`:

```
runAsyncMethod() async {
  print("1");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {print("2");});
  print("3");
}
```

[image]